# calculate gab data between start and end duration

Tags: vba, excel

please i need help in a formula that might be complicated somehow, 
in recap, this sheet have Username, Interval, Chat start time and Chat end time,
i need to export the free time that the agent haven't any chatting time, therefore the agent may have 2 or 3 chat at once,

i used the below code to get the gap between the duration between the end and start chat:

```
Option Explicit

Function DataGap(NameRange As Range, xName As String, StartRange As Range, EndRange As Range, StartTime As Date, Optional EndTime As Date) As Date

Dim GapRange As Range
Dim ShiftRange As Range
'how many seconds in a day?
Const xConv As Long = 86400
Dim intRange As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim missingCells As Long

If EndTime = 0 Then
    'Calculate end of interval
    EndTime = StartTime + TimeValue("0:15:00")
End If



'Build shift range
Set ShiftRange = Range(Cells(StartTime * xConv, 1), Cells(EndTime * xConv, 1))


'Build filled range
For i = 1 To NameRange.Cells.Count
    If NameRange.Cells(i).Value = xName Then
        If GapRange Is Nothing Then
            Set GapRange = Range(Cells(StartRange.Cells(i) * xConv, 1), Cells(EndRange.Cells(i) * xConv, 1))
        Else
            Set GapRange = Union(GapRange, Range(Cells(StartRange.Cells(i) * xConv, 1), Cells(EndRange.Cells(i) * xConv, 1)))
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not GapRange Is Nothing Then
    Set intRange = Intersect(GapRange, ShiftRange)
End If
If intRange Is Nothing Then
    missingCells = ShiftRange.Cells.Count - 1
Else
    missingCells = ShiftRange.Cells.Count - intRange.Cells.Count
End If

DataGap = missingCells / xConv
End Function
```

[image: snapshot]

in recap, this sheet get the free time (Gap) between "Last time" with "Start time), but not totally, there is something go wrong and i can't got it

as shown

the colored cells refer to the wrong occurred values. As the UDF results return in 0 while their is a free time as per the gap between "Last time" with "Start time)

[workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JKSSG5bNRTkEm8CKQmnYri8FTBs9h63c4DQcmH11FwA/edit?usp=sharing)

thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to create a macro for this. This can be done with the help of a simple formula. Use the following steps:

1. Sort the sheet in Ascending order (Smallest to Largest) with `Agent Name` in first level and then `Visit Time` in second level. This will give you a list which has all visit times in sequential order with respect to each agent.
2. Next Insert a column after `Column E`. Our new column will now be `Column F`. Name this column as `Free Time`.
3. In this `Column F` in the first cell (ie. `Cell F2`) paste the formula - `=IF(E2<D3,(D3-E2)*86400,0)`. Populate the rest of the cells with that formula. Now you will have free time for each person in seconds. You may convert it into minutes if you want. (if you have multiple agents on the same sheet use this formula `=IF(A2=A1,IF(E2<D3,(D3-E2)*86400,0),0)` It will ensure that the first row a new agent is found the `free time` is 0.)
4. Now if you want to get a report showing free time for each agent in each of your intervals. Simply select all the data and insert a Pivot Table with `Agent Name` as `Column Label`, `Interval` as `Row Labels` and `Sum of Free Time` as Values. This will give you a neat table showing the free time per agent per interval. Experiment a bit with column labels and row labels to get the right layout.

This could have been done with VBA too but I feel this is the easiest method of doing this. When dealing with VBA for this you can carry on the exact same steps and same logic to find the free time.
Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right about using a formula sorting columns, but the trouble is I've a huge amount of data into the sheet, when sort or apply a calculation, the workbook take long process to figure out the results,so i resorted to use VBA